# Elasticsearch cross cluster search enabling

Tags: elasticsearch

Now we are using 2 separate clusters for storing actual data and log data. Since we have very less data, to reduce the cost we are planning on sending both actual data and log data to one cluster. Actual Data indices are replicated in other data centers and log indices are not replicated. So when we are querying we need to enable the cross-cluster search for log data, since it is not replicated to other datacenters.and for actual data indices we don’t need cross-cluster search because our data is replicated in other data centers. Is that possible when we are querying the log information, can we enable cross-cluster search? and when we are searching data, can we disable in query level? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to register/configure the remote cluster in your local cluster (see Elasticsearch Reference: [Search across clusters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html)). Then you can search across both (local and remote) cluster.